# Obj-C, how can I add a background colour to image I'm adding to cell.imageview, its a PNG?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I am using PNG images to add icons to the rows in my tableview, using

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chart.png"]];
```

This was not a problem before, as my images had black edges and my tableview had black rows. However, I am now providing a light color style as well as dark. So the black edges look rough.

So I thought I would draw the images with a black background.

However, I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` [inherits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from `UIView` so you can just set the `backgroundColor` property to show a color behind the transparant parts of your `png` image

```
[cell.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```